# Step by Step explanation of this code

Tags: python, fibonacci, function

```
def mystery(n):
   a, b = 0, 1
   while a < n:
      print (a)
      a, b = b, a + b
```

If someone could give me a line by line explanation of this code, as also inform of why it will not run, and what extra code needs to be added.

Comment: looks like the output will be a `fibonacci` sequence

Comment: This is the second time (at least) you posted this. Your question is still too broad and unclear. Your function runs just fine, you need to tell what you expected to happen and what happened instead, for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
def mystery(n):  # define a function named "mystery", that takes one argument called "n"
    a, b = 0, 1  # make a variable named "a" and set it to 0; make a variable named "b" and set it to 1
    while a < n:  # as long as "a" is smaller than "n"
       print (a)  # display the value contained in "a" on the screen
       a, b = b, a + b  # set "b" to the sum of "a" and "b"; set "a" to the old value of "b" (before it was set to the sum of "a" and "b")
```

Comment: The question is a re-post and too broad. It is not worth even attempting to answer. You also forgot to divine (read Bob's mind) as to what the function needs to do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is completely off-topic, but the fact that "divine" is a verb just blew my mind. Much more enlightening stuff than this question, many thanks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh! I knew that OP wanted me to christen the function with its functionality. I was being very cheeky and answering what OP asked for, in response to having not put in the effort to write a proper question. I really would have considered revealing the secret identity of the bronze ratio's brother, had OP written up a good question with an attempted solution